# Simple regex matching issue, what's my mistake?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

> 1/45 files checked

I want to parse the numbers (1 and 45) out of it, but first, to check if a string matches this pattern at all. So I write a regex:

```
String line = "1/45 files checked";
Match filesProgressMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"[0-9]+/[0-9]+ files checked");
if (filesProgressMatch.Success)
{
    String matched = filesProgressMatch.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" files checked", "");
    string[] numbers = matched.Split('/');
    filesChecked = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
    totalFiles   = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
}
```

I expected `matched` to contain "1/45", but it is, in fact, empty. What's my mistake? 
My first thought was '/' is a special character in a regex, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

P. S. Is there a better way to parse these values from such string in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is matching, but you are selecting Groups[1] where the count of groups is one. So use

```
String matched = filesProgressMatch.Groups[0].Value.Replace(" files checked", "");
```

And you should be fine

Comment: oh, so _that_'s what a capture group is! So I can avoid `Split` and `Remove`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

You need to escape the forward slash

```
([0-9]+\/[0-9]+) files checked
```

**[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/NaDXQjFlwr)**

Comment: FYI, not only is escaping a slash not required, it breaks the matching (in C#, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Use capture group:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"([0-9]+/[0-9]+) files checked");
#            here __^       and __^
```

You could also use 2 groups:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) files checked");
```

Comment: I'd use *two* capture groups here :)

Answer (score 0):

Applying the replace operation to the first element of `filesProgressMath.Groups` seems to work.

```
String matched = filesProgressMatch.Groups[0].Value.Replace(" files checked", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your results

```
string txtText = @"1\45 files matched";
int[] s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(txtText, "[^\\d+]").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```